# Concatenating two ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have two instances of the same ViewModel that I would like to concatenate:

```
var queryNew = from a in ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups.Find()
                           join e in ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find()
                               on a.AlphaGroupID equals e.AlphaGroupID into g
                           join c in ICDUnitOfWork.Codes.Find()
                               on a.CodeID equals c.CodeID into co
                           select new HomeSearchViewModel
                                      {
                                          Alphas = g,
                                          AlphaGroups = a,
                                          AlphaGroupCode = co.FirstOrDefault(),
                                          SearchTerm = searchTerm,
                                          AlphasCodes = null
                                      };

var codequery = from a in ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find()
                join c in ICDUnitOfWork.Codes.Find()
                on a.CodeID equals c.CodeID into g
                select new HomeSearchViewModel
                       {
                          AlphasCodes = g
                       };

var allResults = queryNew.Concat(codequery);
```

This gives me an error stating:

> *The type 'ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel' appears in two
>   structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to
>   Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same
>   query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and
>   those properties are set in the same order.*

How can I join these results together?

Comment: Did you try what the exception suggests? Didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution was really dumb on my part.  I added a navigation property to the table I was trying join and everything is working now.

whoops!

Answer (score 0):

`Concat` isn't really the right thing to do here, a simple `for` loop should be enough. From the looks of your query you could possibly use the `AlphaGroupCode` as your unique identifier for the mapping e.g.

```
var codequery = ...
                select new HomeSearchViewModel
                {
                    AlphaGroupCode = c.FirstOrDefault()
                    AlphasCodes = g
                };

foreach (var q in queryNew)
{
    q.AlphaCodes = codequery.Where(x => x.AlphaGroupCode == q.AlphaGroupCode)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                            .AlphaCodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try evaluating the queries before hand, calling something like "ToList()":

```
var allResults = queryNew.ToList().Concat(codequery.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing it as two queries then calling `AsEnumerable()` will concatenate in local memory with no problems.

```
var result = queryNew.AsEnumerable().Concat(codequery);
```

Here the `AsEnumerable()` will still defer execution of the queries (which is what your code seems to suggest), however if you want immediate execution do as Arthur suggests and call a cacheing function e.g. `ToList()` or `ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You must fill with null all other properties

```
var codequery = from a in ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find()
                join c in ICDUnitOfWork.Codes.Find()
                on a.CodeID equals c.CodeID into g
                select new HomeSearchViewModel
                       {
                          Alphas = null,
                          AlphaGroups = null,
                          AlphaGroupCode = null,
                          SearchTerm = null,
                          AlphasCodes = g
                       };

var allResults = queryNew.Concat(codequery);
```